# Java enummap confusion

Tags: java, collections, enums, enum-map

Hi Can anyone help me in understanding the following line of code?

```
      private Map<EnumType, Pair<Long, Long>> processToProductLineAndIndustryMap = new EnumMap<EnumType, Pair<Long, Long>>(
        Collections.unmodifiableMap(Stream.of(
                new SimpleEntry<>(EnumType.SOME_TYPE,
                    Pair.of(Question.getProductLineQuestionId(), Question.getAdvertiserIndustryQuestionId())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap((e) -> e.getKey(), (e) -> e.getValue()))));
```

I am new to this. Have went through several articles online but could not able to figure out.

I want to create an unmodifiable  `map<EnumType, Pair<Long, Long>>`. Based on enumtype i want to get the pair of Longs and see if it contains a particular long or not. Please help me in figuring out the best data structure for my usecase

Comment: You are creating a new Map using `EnumMap`s constructor.

Comment: The above is giving error "The method getKey() is undefined for object" ?

Comment: The `Collections.unmodifiableMap` doesn't do anything. This appears to be a complicated way to create a map with one entry.

Comment: I will edit this question with my requirement. Please help me in choosing the best data structure for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collections.singletonMap(key, value)`.

```
private Map<EnumType, Pair<Long, Long>> processToProductLineAndIndustryMap = new EnumMap<EnumType, Pair<Long, Long>>(
        Collections.singletonMap(EnumType.SOME_TYPE, Pair.of(Question.getProductLineQuestionId(), Question.getAdvertiserIndustryQuestionId())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on weekends  :)